# Understanding how to use my Android JSON Parser

Tags: java, android, json

Hello, I'm having a hard time understanding how to do what I want with my JSON parser. I'm currently parsing the data located at http://api.pathofexile.com/leagues?type=all to pull out the league ids (currently they are "Default", "Hardcore", "Feb 12 Solo HC Race", etc.) My parser currently puts these ids into a listview.

The problem I'm having is that these ids will change over time. They also have their own JSON urls that I need to parse based on the league id. For example, if the league id is "Default" I need to take that id and put it into the url:

"api.pathofexile.com/leagues/"+ id +"?ladder=1&ladderOffset=1&ladderLimit=2" to get http://api.pathofexile.com/leagues/Default?ladder=1&ladderOffset=1&ladderLimit=2

Basically, I want to be able to click the id in the listview and have it update the url and parse the new data into a separate list.

Here is what I have for my JSON parser:

```java
public class Leagues extends ListActivity {
    public static String url = "http://api.pathofexile.com/leagues?type=all";

    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    JSONArray leagues = null;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.list_item);
        new GetJSONTask().execute("");
    }

    protected class GetJSONTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> {
        protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> leaguesList;

        private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(Leagues.this);

        // onPreExecute method
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            this.dialog.setMessage("Loading, Please Wait..");
            this.dialog.setCancelable(false);
            this.dialog.show();
        }

        // doInBackground method
        @Override
        protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(String... params) {
            leaguesList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            // defaultHttpClient
            try {
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet HttpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(HttpGet);
                json = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());

                // getting array of entries
                JSONArray leagues = new JSONArray(json);

                // looping through entries
                for (int i = 0; i < leagues.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject league = leagues.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = league.getString(TAG_ID);

                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                    //map.put(TAG_EVENT, event);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    leaguesList.add(map);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return leaguesList;
        }

        // onPostExecute method
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result) {
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(), leaguesList, R.layout.league, new String[] { TAG_ID }, new int[] { R.id.id });
            // selecting single ListView item
            ListView lv = getListView();
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);

            if (this.dialog.isShowing()) {
                this.dialog.dismiss();
            }

        }
    }

}
```

I'm pretty lost at this point. Is what I'm trying to do even possible with how I have the parser set up now? Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

**EDIT for further clarification:**

Right now my parser will put the league ids into a ListView from the url "api.pathofexile.com/leagues?type=all" like below:

1. Default
2. Hardcore
3. Feb 12 Solo HC Race

(These items will change over time)

I want to be able to click on "Default," which will change the url to "api.pathofexile.com/leagues/Default?ladder=1&ladderOffset=1&ladderLimit=2" and parse it into a new ListView.

**UPDATE:**
Using the project provided by Darwind, I changed it around (using some of my other code) to show the JSON data that I wanted after clicking on the league id.

```java
public class LeagueView extends ListActivity {
    //private TextView leagueId, leagueDescription;
    private static final String TAG_LADDER = "ladder";
    private static final String TAG_ENTRIES = "entries";
    private static final String TAG_ONLINE = "online";
    private static final String TAG_RANK = "rank";
    private static final String TAG_CHARACTER = "character";
    private static final String TAG_CHARNAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_LEVEL = "level";
    private static final String TAG_CLASS = "class";
    private static final String TAG_EXPERIENCE = "experience";
    private static final String TAG_ACCOUNT = "account";
    private static final String TAG_ACCNAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_ACCNAME2 = "name2";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.league_layout);

    //leagueId = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.leagueId);
    //leagueDescription = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.leagueDescription);

    String urlToJson = getIntent().getExtras().getString("leagueUrl");

    if (urlToJson == null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Url was null!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        new LeagueTask().execute(urlToJson.replaceAll(" ", "%20"));
    }
}

protected class LeagueTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, League> {
    private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(LeagueView.this);
    protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> entriesList;

    // onPreExecute method
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        this.dialog.setMessage("Retrieving Ladder Information...");
        this.dialog.setCancelable(false);
        this.dialog.show();
    }

    // doInBackground method
    @Override
    protected League doInBackground(String... params) {
        League aLeague = new League();
        entriesList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // defaultHttpClient
        try {
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet HttpGet = new HttpGet(params[0]);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(HttpGet);
            String json = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());

            // Getting a JSONObject filled.
            JSONObject leagueObject = new JSONObject(json);

            //String id = leagueObject.getString("id");
            //String description = leagueObject.getString("description");

            JSONObject ladder = leagueObject.getJSONObject(TAG_LADDER);
            JSONArray entries = ladder.getJSONArray(TAG_ENTRIES);

            // looping through entries
            for (int i = 0; i < entries.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject ent = entries.getJSONObject(i);

                // storing each JSON item in a variable
                String online = ent.getString(TAG_ONLINE);
                if (online == "false")
                    online = "Offline";
                else online = "Online";
                String rank = ent.getString(TAG_RANK);

                // pull out character object
                JSONObject character = ent.getJSONObject(TAG_CHARACTER);
                String chName = character.getString(TAG_CHARNAME);
                String lvl = character.getString(TAG_LEVEL);
                String cl = character.getString(TAG_CLASS);
                String xp = character.getString(TAG_EXPERIENCE);

                // pull out account object
                JSONObject account = ent.getJSONObject(TAG_ACCOUNT);
                String accName = account.getString(TAG_ACCNAME);

                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                map.put(TAG_ONLINE, online);
                map.put(TAG_CHARNAME, chName);
                map.put(TAG_ACCNAME2, accName);
                map.put(TAG_RANK, rank);
                map.put(TAG_LEVEL, lvl);
                map.put(TAG_EXPERIENCE, xp);
                map.put(TAG_CLASS, cl);

                entriesList.add(map);
            }

            // creating a league to display
            aLeague = new League();
            //aLeague.setLeagueId(id);
            //aLeague.setDescription(description);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return aLeague;
    }

    // onPostExecute method
    protected void onPostExecute(League result) {
        //leagueId.setText(result.getLeagueId());
        //leagueDescription.setText(result.getDescription());

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(), entriesList, R.layout.league_layout, new String[] { TAG_RANK, TAG_CHARNAME, TAG_LEVEL, TAG_EXPERIENCE, TAG_CLASS }, new int[] { R.id.rank, R.id.chName, R.id.lvl, R.id.experience, R.id.cl });
        // selecting single ListView item
        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        if (this.dialog.isShowing()) {
            this.dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: The code looks about right in regards to parsing the JSON array. However why are you creating a new HashMap for each item in the JSON array? 
Instead of doing that, you could create a new kind of object for holding informations about the different kinds of leagues and then override the toString method for this object to be able to display the name nicely in the ListView.

Comment: I based my code off of an example I saw and modified it to fit my JSON and made it into an AsyncTask. Any suggestions for modifying it what you're saying? Also, would that make it easier parse a new url when clicking on a ListView item?

Comment: Sure, but tell me, are you getting any exceptions, are your code not working or are you just asking for some pointers as how to pass on a given row in the ListView to an AsyncTask and get a reply back for the specific row's id?

Comment: Everything works fine with no errors. I just don't understand what I need to do to have a clickable id, which will update the url to be parsed, then parse that url into a new list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so, basically as vsnyc pointed out your title is probably a bit misleading.

The way I see it, is this:

1. Get a list of all leagues from parsing a JSON Array
2. Be able to click a league in the list and get a view supplying info about the selected league, by parsing a JSON Object.

I basically went and kanged all your code and changed it a bit. For instance I mentioned in a comment, that you should use a class to represent every league and then override the `toString` method for this new kind of object, so that this class could be used directly in your `ListView`.

As the first url you're using: `http://api.pathofexile.com/leagues?type=all` is returning a JSON Array and not a single object and the objects inside this array is different from the data returned when selecting a specific league, I wouldn't recommend to use the same AsyncTask for getting both the list of leagues and a single league.

Instead after you've populated the first `ListView` with leagues, I would create a second view, that is populated by getting data from a specific league.

To get to the second view representing one league, you need to implement the `OnItemClickListener` for the `ListView` of the first view. In the `OnItemClickListener` you will get the selected leagues name and pass it to the next view which in turn will contact the server and get the `JSON` object representing the given league and parse the data.

I've created a small project as this was quite a lot of code to add to the answer and it would take me more time to remove all unnecessary code, than just to give you a full working project. ;-)

Here's the project in a zip file:

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/27724371/AndroidListViews.zip

Let me know if this wasn't what you were looking for.

Comment: This is almost exactly what I was looking for. I updated the OP with a modified version of your LeagueView class. Does that look alright, or is there anything wrong with the way I'm doing it? Right now, when I click on a league id, it outputs [**this**](http://i.imgur.com/d14iJ1K.png), which is what I want. Is there a more efficient way, or is it fine?

Comment: Well I don't know exactly why you keep using that HashMap<String, String> since it doesn't make sense, and in the new code you supplied you're not using the League object you're returning.
Instead of using a simple ArrayList with HashMaps inside you should extend the League class I created and maybe create a new class called Hero or something and have a list of Hero objects inside the League class. Another possibility is to create and return a list of Hero objects. The way you're using the HashMaps is just not right - you can do it, it's just not the right approach in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not to write a parser yourself but use the one that JSON developed 
http://json.org/java/

Comment: I am using these imports: org.json.JSONArray;
org.json.JSONException;
org.json.JSONObject;

Answer (score 0):

Jophess, I'm editing my answer.

So I mocked out your code and ran it locally. Now I see what you are trying to do. There are two parts to your question. I think the question description is ill-named, your description seems to focus on a clickable listview item but your summary seems to be around parsing json.

<strike>Also note that http://api.pathofexile.com/leagues/Hardcore?ladder=1&ladderOffset=1&ladderLimit=2 is not giving a properly formatted json text, square braces at the beginning and end are missing.</strike> This wasn't correct, it is returning a single JSONObject not an array

First part: making a list view item clickable, use ListView.setOnItemClickListener to make an item clickable. e.g. see this tutorial: http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1351248

Second part what should happen when you click. Part of it will go to the implementation of setOnItemClickListener and the second portion is JSON of building the new link and having it clicked and content returned. You are returning ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> leaguesList; which seems very limiting, why would you not return JSONArray itself or ArrayList<HashMap<String,JSONObject>> where the map has ID as the key and all the elements in JSONObject that you could later use, unless ID is the only thing you are interested in?

I don't have an android simulator handy but if you need any help with the JSON parser, let me know.

This is how I imagine it working, the onclick event will build a new url from

```
        public static String PATTERN =
          "http://api.pathofexile.com/leagues/" + ID_TOKEN +
          "?ladder=1&ladderOffset=1&ladderLimit=2";
```

using a passed in Url encoded ID, e.g. Default, Feb 15 Solo HC Race and will call the GetJSONTask.doInBackGround task to get a new JSON array.

Comment: He's asking if he's doing something wrong, not how to use a JSON parser in Groovy...

Comment: Thanks Darwind, I have not had a more helpful response. FWIW, I was just suggesting not to reinvent the wheel but I see that Jophess is using default java json parsers, so it's good

Comment: If you had actually read his question (including code) you would've seen that he didn't re-invent the wheel - he was actually using a library already written.
So no problem... I was just pointing out that you weren't really answering his question - hence the -1.

Comment: Removing the -1 as you improved the answer. Just one thing: the JSON returned by http://api.pathofexile.com/leagues/Hardcore?ladder=1&ladderOffset=1&ladderLimit=2 is correct. It doesn't need the [] around it as it's a single JSON object...

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense :) I reused JSONArray leagues = new JSONArray(json); in my mock code and was getting a JSONException.